# Querying EF Core identity roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 and I want to query the users in my database.

So I modified my `ApplicationUser` class as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<IdentityUserRole<string>> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

And now I'm trying to query the Users.

```
var users = from u in DbContext.Users
            select new UserViewModel
            {
                Email = u.Email,
                EmailConfirmed = u.EmailConfirmed,
                Phone = u.PhoneNumber,
                Roles = u.UserRoles.Select(r => r.Role.Name) // Whoops! Won't work
            };
```

The problem is that `UserRoles` have a `RoleId` property, but they don't have a `Role` property.

So how would I get the name of those roles?

**Update:**

Based on Jawad's comments, I changed my code as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
Users = (from u in DbContext.Users
         select new UserViewModel
         {
             Email = u.Email,
             EmailConfirmed = u.EmailConfirmed,
             Phone = u.PhoneNumber,
             Roles = u.Roles.Select(r => r.Name)
         })
         .ToList();
```

I was thinking I couldn't do that because it's a many-to-many relationship. But in fact, it does compile. However, when I run it I get an error.

> Invalid column name 'ApplicationUserId'.

I'm not sure where that column name is being referenced. It doesn't appear to be a column name in the database.

**Update 2:**

Turns out, the error above is because a database migration was pending. However, I didn't want to change the database. As I initially suspected, I can't do `ApplicationUser.ICollection<IdentityRole>` because there is an intermediate table.

So I got this to run, but it returned no results (because there are no foreign keys from `IdentityRole` to `ApplicationUser`.

So, the question stands: how can I query users along with their roles?

Comment: Can't you add the `Role` property to `UserRoles`?

Comment: @cantSleepNow: Not sure what you mean. As you can see, `UsersRoles` is of type `ICollection<IdentityUserRoles<string>>`, and `IdentityUserRole<>` is defined in the .NET Core library. I can't edit it.

Comment: yup, saw it now, didn't realize immediately it's a net core class

Comment: are you sure you are not looking for `IdentityRoles` instead of `IdentityUserRoles` ? `IdentityUserRoles` only has `RoleId` and `UserId` as members where `IdentityRoles` has a Name field. With `IdentityRoles`, you can use `u.UserRoles.Select(r => r.Name)` without the Role.

Comment: @Jawad: Well, it's a many-to-many relationship so I'm not sure if you can do that. Anyway, `IdentityRoles` is not defined for me. What version are you using?

Comment: IdentityRole is defined in the AspNetCore.Identity assembly: Assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60/ (.Net Core 3.0)

Comment: @Jawad: Yes, `IdentityRole` is defined (not `IdentityRoles`). And in fact, that does compile. But when I run it I get an error *Invalid column name 'ApplicationUserId'.*

Comment: Where are you looking up the applicationUserId ?

Comment: I'm not. I've updated my question with the new code.

Comment: @Jawad: I figured out the error (see updates to my question). But this doesn't work. The `IdentityRole` table does not have a foreign key to my `ApplicationUser` table. I need to deal with the intermediary table, `IdentityUserRole`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a new class called something like `ApplicationUserRole` that inherits from `IdentityUserRole<string>` then you just need to define the relationships between `ApplicationUser` -> `ApplicationUserRole` and `ApplicationRole` -> `ApplicationUserRole`.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>(entity =>
{
    entity
      .HasOne(x => x.Role)
      .WithMany(x => x.UserRoles)
      .HasForeignKey(x => x.RoleId);

    entity
      .HasOne(x => x.User)
      .WithMany(x => x.UserRoles)
      .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
 });
```

You should also replace any references to the Identity classes with your Application classes.

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string>
{
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<string>
{
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @JonathanWood It's not duplicated, it's linking `ApplicationUserRole` to `ApplicationUser` and `ApplicationUserRole` to `ApplicationRole`

Comment: Like I said, I have it working and adding this other stuff for a single query is not worthwhile for me. But without actually testing it, this looks like the right answer. I still think `IdentityUserRole` should have a `IdentityRole` property, but I'm marking this as the right answer (over mine).

Answer (score 2):

So, I don't know why `IdentityUserRole` doesn't include an `IdentityRole` property. This seems to be an unnecessary limitation.

In the end, I just changed my query.

```
var users = await (from u in DbContext.Users
                   join ur in DbContext.UserRoles on u.Id equals ur.UserId
                   join r in DbContext.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                   select new
                   {
                       u.Email,
                       u.EmailConfirmed,
                       u.PhoneNumber,
                       Role = r.Name
                   })
                   .ToListAsync();

Users = (from u in users
         group u.Role by u into g
         select new UserViewModel
         {
             Email = g.Key.Email,
             EmailConfirmed = g.Key.EmailConfirmed,
             Phone = g.Key.PhoneNumber,
             Roles = string.Join(", ", g)
         })
         .ToList();
```

I couldn't get the `group by` to work within the query so I'm group it after the data has been retrieved.

Anyway, it works.